# Loading Thumbnails with YouTube Data API

Tags: json, swift, youtube-api, alamofire

I'm using the YouTube API and Alamofire to show videos for my YouTube channel. I'm having an issue that the thumbnails for the videos are messing up when scrolling. Like this:

[image]

I used Apple videos for the example. For some reason, the colors got messed up when creating the GIF, though. But you get the idea. Here are my relevant view controllers

**TableViewController**

```
import UIKit

class VideosTableViewController: UITableViewController, VideoModelDelegate {

    var videos: [Video] = [Video]()
    var selectedVideo:Video?

    let model:VideoModel = VideoModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if tableView.rowHeight == 250 {
            tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 250
        } else {
            tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 96
        }

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        model.getFeedVideo()
        self.model.delegate = self
        dataReady()

        //
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func handleRefresh() {
        dataReady()
        refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    }


    func dataReady() {
        print("dataReady()")
        self.videos = self.model.videoArray
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return videos.count
    }



    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        // Configure the cell...
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
        var cell : NewVideoTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "New Cell") as! NewVideoTableViewCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = videos[indexPath.row].videoTitle
            cell.thumbnail.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.thumbnail.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            let videoThumbnailURLString = videos[indexPath.row].videoThumbnailUrl
            let videoThumbnailUrl = NSURL(string: videoThumbnailURLString)

            if videoThumbnailUrl != nil {
                let request = NSURLRequest(url: videoThumbnailUrl! as URL)
                let session = URLSession.shared
                let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        cell.thumbnail.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    }

                })

                dataTask.resume()

            }

            return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let videoTitle = videos[indexPath.row].videoTitle

        let title = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        title.text = videoTitle

        let videoThumbnailURLString = videos[indexPath.row].videoThumbnailUrl
        let videoThumbnailUrl = NSURL(string: videoThumbnailURLString)
        let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

        if videoThumbnailUrl != nil {
            let request = NSURLRequest(url: videoThumbnailUrl! as URL)
            let session = URLSession.shared
            let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)

                }

            })

            imageView.clipsToBounds = true
            imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
            imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.1

        dataTask.resume()

        }

        return cell
        }
    }
}
```

**VideoModel**

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

protocol VideoModelDelegate {
    func dataReady()
}

let API_KEY = "My API Key"
let UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID = "My Playlist"
let CHANNEL_ID = "My Channel ID"
let parameters = ["part":"snippet","maxResults":50,"channelId":CHANNEL_ID,"playlistId":UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID,"key":API_KEY] as [String : Any]

class VideoModel: NSObject {

    var videoArray = [Video]()

    var delegate: VideoModelDelegate?

    func getFeedVideo() {
        Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

            if let JSON = response.result.value {

                if let dictionary = JSON as? [String: Any] {

                    var arrayOfVideos = [Video]()

                    guard let items = dictionary["items"] as? NSArray else { return }

                    for items in dictionary["items"] as! NSArray {
                        print(items)
                        //  Create video objects off of the JSON response

                        let videoObj = Video()
                        videoObj.videoID = (items as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "snippet.resourceId.videoId") as! String
                        videoObj.videoTitle = (items as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "snippet.title") as! String
                        videoObj.videoDescription = (items as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "snippet.description") as! String
                        videoObj.videoThumbnailUrl = (items as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url") as! String


                        arrayOfVideos.append(videoObj)

                    }
                    self.videoArray = arrayOfVideos
                    if self.delegate != nil {
                        self.delegate!.dataReady()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Video**

```
import UIKit

class Video: NSObject {

    var videoID:String = ""
    var videoTitle:String = ""
    var videoDescription:String = ""
    var videoThumbnailUrl:String = ""        

}
```

So, do you see how the thumbnails get are jumpy? Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which iOS version are you targeting ? What's the problem: "jumpy" thumbnails or gif color issues ?

Comment: @nathan The thumbnails. The gif is just a screen capture of my app to show the problem.

Comment: So the problem is that there's a delay in the data loading ? You need to implement prefetching and/or use a caching library (E.g: PINRemoteImage, which has support for GIFs also)

Comment: The view is being recycled and retains the old image from a previous row before the new one has completed loading. Set the thumbnail to a placeholder image (even blank) before attempting to load the new thumbnail.